# PHP Associative array. Get key value pair using foreach

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I'm trying to define a function that, given an associative array, would echo the key value pair, given an argument for that function.

So far I have the code that appears below. However, the result of that code would be a complete list (table) of the key-value pairs. What I'm trying to get is just ONE pair (once the function is called).

Could anybody help me?

Thanks!

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<body>

<h1>List of States</h1>

<?php

$states = array ("AL"=>"Alabama","AK"=>"Alaska","AZ"=>"Arizona","AR"=>"Arkansas","CA"=>"California","CO"=>"Colorado","CT"=>"Connecticut",
"DE"=>"Delaware","FL"=>"Florida","GA"=>"Georgia","HI"=>"Hawaii","ID"=>"Idaho","IL"=>"Illinois","IN"=>"Indiana","IA"=>"Iowa","KS"=>"Kansas",
"KY"=>"Kentucky");

function printState($Abbr) {

    global $states;

        echo "<table border=1>";

    foreach($states as $Abbr => $value) {   

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $Abbr;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }

        echo "</table>";

}

printState("CA");


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `echo $states[$Abbr];` suffice?

Comment: So you just want to print 1 key/value pair each time you call the function OR do you want to get the specific value to that key which you pass to the function?

Comment: Hey. I just want to print ONE pair, once the function is called. Meaning, if I passed the key "CA", I'd like to get a table just with one row, that includes the key (CA) and the state name (California).
BTW, I tried echoing $states[$Abbr];, but I get the complete list of states.

Comment: @EmilioZaidman That shouldn't happen based on your code. If you remove all of the code, except for the array, and do something like `echo $states["CA"];`, you should get California (and only California).

Comment: That's correct. I did that and worked. But I'm only getting the value, not the key. The code that Jamie gave me (I don't know how to mention him) worked just fine.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must have a function:

```
function getState($code) {
    global $states;
    if (array_key_exists($code, $states)) {
        return $states[$code];
    }
    return false;
}

echo getState('GA');
```

But as [Dave Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2344142/dave-chen) suggested, `$states[$abbr];` is how you'd do it.

Comment: But `in_array` checks if the value exists as a value and `$code` would be the key to the array. I think it should be `array_key_exists`

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can also use this

```
function printState($Abbr) {
    global $states;
if (array_key_exists($Abbr,$states)){   
    return "<table border=1><tr><td>$Abbr</td><td>$states[$Abbr]</td></tr></table>";
    }
}
echo printState("AK");
?>
```